# Logging linenumbers with SLF4J and Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, slf4j

When running Apache Beam Google Dataflow jobs and using the SLF4J logger we don't get anything beyond the log message in Stack Driver. 
Example of additional information would be function, line number etc.

Is there anyway to configure the logger like a log4j.xml or java logging properties file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to customize logs messages in Dataflow other than what is shown in this [logging pipelines messages](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging)

Have you looked at [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging)? It has several features such as Custom logs / Ingestion API. In case you haven't, take a look at this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java#logback_appender_for) to setup the SLF4J logging facade through Logback appender and Cloud Logging. Once you have configured Logback to use the Cloud Logging, you can use the SLF4J logging API. Another option is to use the Cloud Logging API with a default Java Logging API handler, which can be added programmatically or by using a configuration file, here is an [example](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java#example_2) using logger.

Answer (score 0):

Isaac Miliani, I tried the same option google cloud logging as provided in the google cloud docs,

1. Added logback.xml to src/main/resources (classpath).
2. Created loggingeventenhancer and enhancer class to add new labels.
3. Added markers to logger error, to find the type of error in Stackdriver.
4. But the logs in stackdriver doesnt have new labels added via logging appender. I think the logback.xml is not found by the maven compile command to deploy the job in dataflow.

Can you provide whats going on wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be due to how logging is implemented in beam where the record is parsed into some of the fields and context to other fields, but you can only control the record. https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/ef581e7ad44e7405a3ab15e2cafac0fb13a8c936/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/worker/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/worker/logging/DataflowWorkerLoggingHandler.java#L123